# hidesBackButton / setHidesBackButton not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have some problem in my application.

In my application there is a possibility to edit some information (something like iPhone's contacts). When you press 'Edit' button on right of navigation bar, "Back" button should hide, and "Cancel" button appear.

It working perfectly, when user press "Edit" button straight from ViewController.

But, when user creating a new advert, the view controller with editing should open, in edit mode. I call it this way:

```
VICarInfo * vc = [[VICarInfo alloc] init];
[vc setCurrentAdv:adv];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

if (editMode) {
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
    [vc btnEditClick];
}
```

And "Back" button didn't disappear.

I also tried to hide button in ViewWillAppear, ViewDidLoad or ViedDidLayout subviews, also unsuccessful.

[image: Simulator]

Please, give me any advices, how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: TLDR: `vc.navigationItem.hidesBackButton` instead of `navigationItem.hidesBackButton`  - Understand that the `Navigation Item` used by the `Navigation Controller` is the one owned **by** the `View Controller` that you are going to push. Which means that you need to modify the back button setting in the NavigationItem of the VC you're presenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is late, but I was seeing the same thing and found a solution.

It seems that hidesBackButton = YES interferes with setting the leftBarButtonItem(s).

Don't use hidesBackButton and you'll lose the overlay.

This seems like a bug, but Apple's own documentation is pretty hazy on the interaction of those two/three properties.

Answer (score 13):

Use this :

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one..

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Comment: Right now what problem you'r getting

Comment: Just the same, nothing changed.

Comment: This is working at my end. So please check your code might be problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 5.0:

self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = ?;

NO - having leftBarButtonItems hides the backButtonItem (default), 
YES - leftBarButtonItems co-exist with the backButtonItem

There still seems to be an iOS 7 bug however, that hides (or not) the backButtonItem indiscriminately.

Answer (score 0):

try on real device . showing custom image on real device  . But not ios simulator . if you do test on simulator , you will see ios default back button .

Answer (score 0):

1. Set leftBarButtonItem to a custom button
2. hide or show that button using isHidden property
   (iOS 16+ onwards: old trash does not have that API)